# How to access user space function arguments in bpf?

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf, libbpf

I am trying to instrument a user space nginx function by using `libbpf`. I am able to attach a uprobe it, and print `pid`, `tid` and so on from the probe. However, I am having great issues whenever I try to parse function argument data. I have been able to do this with `bpftrace` but am unable to do so with `libbpf`. My question is, how to properly access and print arguments of the user space function I want to trace?

**nginx.bpf.c**

```c
#include "ngx_http.h"
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_core_read.h>

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";

SEC("uprobe//usr/sbin/nginx:ngx_http_finalize_request")
int handle_ngx_http_finalize_request(struct ngx_http_request_s* r, ngx_int_t rc)
{
    u_char *s_ptr;
    u_char str[128];
    int err;

    err = bpf_probe_read_user(&s_ptr, sizeof(s_ptr), &r->request_line.data);
    if (!s_ptr || err < 0) {
        bpf_printk("Error %d\n", err);
        return -2;
    }

    bpf_probe_read_user_str(str, sizeof(str), &s_ptr);

    bpf_printk("String: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to parse the function arguments the `bpf_probe_read_user` returns error `-14`. When I try to use `bpf_core_read` the verifier rejects the code with following error.

```
❯ sudo ./nginx
libbpf: loading object 'nginx_bpf' from buffer
libbpf: elf: section(3) uprobe//usr/sbin/nginx:ngx_http_finalize_request, size 280, link 0, flags 6, type=1
libbpf: sec 'uprobe//usr/sbin/nginx:ngx_http_finalize_request': found program 'handle_ngx_http_finalize_request' at insn offset 0 (0 bytes), code size 35 insns (280 bytes)
libbpf: elf: section(4) .reluprobe//usr/sbin/nginx:ngx_http_finalize_request, size 32, link 12, flags 40, type=9
libbpf: elf: section(5) license, size 13, link 0, flags 3, type=1
libbpf: license of nginx_bpf is Dual BSD/GPL
libbpf: elf: section(6) .rodata, size 22, link 0, flags 2, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(7) .BTF, size 12720, link 0, flags 0, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(9) .BTF.ext, size 252, link 0, flags 0, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(12) .symtab, size 240, link 1, flags 0, type=2
libbpf: looking for externs among 10 symbols...
libbpf: collected 0 externs total
libbpf: map 'nginx_bp.rodata' (global data): at sec_idx 6, offset 0, flags 80.
libbpf: map 0 is "nginx_bp.rodata"
libbpf: sec '.reluprobe//usr/sbin/nginx:ngx_http_finalize_request': collecting relocation for section(3) 'uprobe//usr/sbin/nginx:ngx_http_finalize_request'
libbpf: sec '.reluprobe//usr/sbin/nginx:ngx_http_finalize_request': relo #0: insn #13 against '.rodata'
libbpf: prog 'handle_ngx_http_finalize_request': found data map 0 (nginx_bp.rodata, sec 6, off 0) for insn 13
libbpf: sec '.reluprobe//usr/sbin/nginx:ngx_http_finalize_request': relo #1: insn #28 against '.rodata'
libbpf: prog 'handle_ngx_http_finalize_request': found data map 0 (nginx_bp.rodata, sec 6, off 0) for insn 28
libbpf: loading kernel BTF '/sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux': 0
libbpf: map 'nginx_bp.rodata': created successfully, fd=4
libbpf: sec 'uprobe//usr/sbin/nginx:ngx_http_finalize_request': found 1 CO-RE relocations
libbpf: prog 'handle_ngx_http_finalize_request': relo #0: <byte_off> [2] typedef ngx_http_request_t.request_line.data (0:21:1 @ offset 992)
libbpf: prog 'handle_ngx_http_finalize_request': relo #0: no matching targets found
libbpf: prog 'handle_ngx_http_finalize_request': relo #0: substituting insn #1 w/ invalid insn
libbpf: prog 'handle_ngx_http_finalize_request': BPF program load failed: Invalid argument
libbpf: prog 'handle_ngx_http_finalize_request': -- BEGIN PROG LOAD LOG --
R1 type=ctx expected=fp
; int handle_ngx_http_finalize_request(ngx_http_request_t* r, ngx_int_t rc)
0: (bf) r3 = r1
1: <invalid CO-RE relocation>
failed to resolve CO-RE relocation <byte_off> [2] typedef ngx_http_request_t.request_line.data (0:21:1 @ offset 992)
processed 2 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
libbpf: prog 'handle_ngx_http_finalize_request': failed to load: -22
libbpf: failed to load object 'nginx_bpf'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'nginx_bpf': -22
Failed to open and load BPF skeleton
```

Here is `bpftrace` code that works.

**nginx.bt**

```c
uprobe:/usr/sbin/nginx:ngx_http_finalize_request
{
    $req = (struct ngx_http_request_s*)arg0;
    printf("Request Line: %s\n", str($req->request_line.data));
}
```

So I would like to parse data and do some custom logic depending on it.

Here are the [`ngx_http_request_s`](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/ngx_http_request.h#L377) and the [`ngx_str_t`](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/core/ngx_string.h#L16-L19) structs for the curious.

### EDIT

---

User space code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <bpf/libbpf.h>
#include "nginx.skel.h"

static int libbpf_print_fn(enum libbpf_print_level level, const char *format, va_list args)
{
    return vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct nginx_bpf *skel;
    int err;

    libbpf_set_strict_mode(LIBBPF_STRICT_ALL);
    libbpf_set_print(libbpf_print_fn);

    skel = nginx_bpf__open_and_load();
    if (!skel) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open and load BPF skeleton\n");
        return 1;
    }

    err = nginx_bpf__attach(skel);
    if (err) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to auto-attach BPF skeleton: %d\n", err);
            goto cleanup;
    }

    printf("Successfully started!\n");

    for (;;) {
        sleep(1);
    }

cleanup:
    nginx_bpf__destroy(skel);
    return -err;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are actually not defining BPF program correctly. You should do something like the below. Note that you also shouldn't use CO-RE variants of `bpf_core_read()` or `BPF_CORE_READ()`, use `BPF_PROBE_READ_USER()` instead:

```
SEC("uprobe//usr/sbin/nginx:ngx_http_finalize_request")
int BPF_KPROBE(handle_ngx_http_finalize_request,
               struct ngx_http_request_s* r, ngx_int_t rc)
{
    u_char *s_ptr;
    u_char str[128];
    int err;

    /* you can access rc directly now, btw */

    s_ptr = BPF_PROBE_READ_USER(r, request_line.data);
    /* note no dereferencing of s_ptr above */
    bpf_probe_read_user_str(str, sizeof(str), s_ptr); 

    bpf_printk("String: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
```

You don't have to use `BPF_PROBE_READ_USER()` macro, you can do the same with just `bpf_probe_read_user()` like you did in your example. `BPF_PROBE_READ_USER()` will be especially handy if you need to follow few levels of pointers, though.

But there is no CO-RE for user-space types, it's only for kernel types, because kernel provides BTF information to allow relocating offsets properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still unnable to actually access the contents of `ngx_http_request_s` struct. The output of `str` array is empty... Could this error be related to me omitting the calculation of the function offset in the user space code? I have update the original post with the user space code. I have omitted the offset calc due to the code being to seemingly load properly.

Comment: what error does bpf_probe_read_user_str() return? if it's -EFAULT, then either s_ptr value is incorrect, or to get that memory requires page fault and uprobe programs don't allow faults.

Comment: It is indeed -EFAULT. Considering our [previous discussion](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf-bootstrap/discussions/133#discussioncomment-4365389), I am more inclined to believe that the s_ptr value is incorrect, as the bpf program is unable to read system-wide headers, and therefore gets the memory address wrong somehow. Also not entirely sure how a page fault might occur in this context, as the value I am trying to access is already on the stack.

Comment: Revisiting this, in what way can the value be 'incorrect'? I've tried the same with `rc` where the type is defined as `typedef intptr_t ngx_int_t`, and getting the same results.